# Can't Http Delete Method on Simple PHP API using Silex - exceeded subrequest limit

Tags: php, apache, rest, eloquent, silex

I'm trying to get the hang of PHP and REST by writing a simple shopping list application. At the moment, I'm able to GET and POST to the API, however, everytime  I try to run the DELETE method, I'm getting a 500 Internal Server error and the following in my apache Log:

```
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.554267 2019] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12459] mod_socache_shmcb.c(495): AH00831: 
socache_shmcb_store (0x0c -> subcache 12)                                                              
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.554393 2019] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12459] mod_socache_shmcb.c(849): AH00847: 
insert happened at idx=0, data=(0:32)                                                                  
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.554432 2019] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12459] mod_socache_shmcb.c(854): AH00848: 
finished insert, subcache: idx_pos/idx_used=0/1, data_pos/data_used=0/222                              
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.554459 2019] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 12459] mod_socache_shmcb.c(516): AH00834: 
leaving socache_shmcb_store successfully                                                               
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.560611 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 12459] ssl_engine_kernel.c(377): [client 192.168.69.
2:51738] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 3 (server smart-shopper.notsoslow.tk:
443)                                                                                                   
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.561836 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12459] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168
.69.2:51738] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted                             
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.561898 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12459] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168
.69.2:51738] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted                                    
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563184 2019] [core:error] [pid 12459] [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH00125: Request
 exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInte
rnalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.            
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563308 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3833): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00121: r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                                             
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563334 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563358 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563381 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563402 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563423 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563444 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563519 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563545 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563566 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/index.php                           
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.563590 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12459] core.c(3847): [client 192.168.69.2:51738] AH
00123: subrequested from r->uri = /smart-shopper-api/shopping-list/1                                   
[Mon Jul 22 12:39:51.564841 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 12459] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 192.168.69.2:5
1738] AH02001: Connection closed to child 3 with standard shutdown (server smart-shopper.notsoslow.tk:4
43)
```

Here's what my index.php looks like:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
include 'bootstrap.php';

use smart_shopper_api\Models\ShoppingListItem;
use smart_shopper_api\Middleware\Logging as ApiLogging;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response as Response;

$app = new Silex\Application();
// never use in production
$app['debug'] = true;
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$app->before(function($request, $app) {
    ApiLogging::log($request, $app);
});

$app->get('/shopping-list', function () use ($app) {
    $_shoppingList = new ShoppingListItem();
    $shoppingListItems = $_shoppingList->all();

    $payload = [];

    foreach ($shoppingListItems as $_item) {
        $payload[$_item->id] = [
            'name' => $_item->name,
            'description' => $_item->description,
            'price' => $_item->price,
            'created_at' => $_item->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $_item->updated_at
        ];
    }

    return $app->json($payload, 200);
});

$app->post('/shopping-list', function(Request $request) use($app) {

    $_name = $request->get('name');
    $_description = $request->get('description');
    $_price = $request->get('price');

    $shoppingListItem = new ShoppingListItem();
    $shoppingListItem->name = $_name;
    $shoppingListItem->description = $_description;
    $shoppingListItem->price = $_price;

    $shoppingListItem->save();

    if($shoppingListItem->id) {
        $code = 201;
        $payload = [
            'id' => $shoppingListItem->id
        ];
    } else {
        $code = 400;
        $payload = [];
    }

    return $app->json($payload, $code);
});

$app->delete('/shopping-list/{item_id}', function($item_id) use($app) {
    $shoppingListItem = ShoppingListItem::where('id', $item_id);
    if($shoppingListItem != null) {
        $shoppingListItem->delete();
    } else {
        return new Response('Shopping List Item not found. It may be deleted before or it may have never existed.', 200);
    }

    if($shoppingListItem->exists) {
        return new Response('', 400);
    } else {
        return new Response('', 204);
    }
});

$app->get('/test', function () use ($app) {

    return "This route confirms that Silex is running. This doesn't contain a call to the Database However.";
});

$app->run();
```

I did some research on what "AH00125: Request
 exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInte
rnalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace." meant, and I was able to change the Internal recursion to 1000, however it created 1000 entries, so something is looping that I can't put my finger on.

Here's my VirtualHost Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/apache2/smart-shopper/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/apache2/smart-shopper/key.pem

        ServerName smart-shopper.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        Alias /smart-shopper-api/ /var/www/html/smart-shopper/smart-shopper-api/
        <Directory "/var/www/html/smart-shopper/smart-shopper-api/">
                FallbackResource index.php
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/smart-shopper/smart-shopper-api/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/smart-shopper-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/smart-shopper-access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Still struggling with this one. I'm going to try spinning up another server with Nginx. Perhaps it's an apache2 limitation, or a limitation in my knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I couldn't sort this in Apache and I changed the web server software.

Before the web server was running Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 and I've changed this over to nginx. Here's what my Nginx virtualhost config looks like for anyone who might struggle with the same thing:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/certs/key.key;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/smart-shopper/smart-shopper-api;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mywebsite.com;

        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
                break;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

So it's working now, and that's the main thing. And now I'm using Nginx for everything because I couldn't work this out in Apache. So bazaar you cannot run DELETE method with rewrite back to the index.php. Perhaps someone might know the answer to that, however for now this is the best path ahead.